# Onsubmit isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onsubmit

The "onsubmit" isn't working in this code. Can someone help me? It doesn't get to the function. I put there a alert but it didn't react. So it seems like the onsubmit just doesn't do it's work.

It's about the submit in the input

```
    <form onSubmit="maakCookie('user',document.inlog.gebruiker.value,1); maakCookie('password',document.inlog.wachtwoord.value,1);" 
name="inlog" action="inloggen.html" method="post"> email-adres: 
<input type="text" size="20" id="gebruiker" /> 
wachtwoord: <input type="password" size="20" 
id="wachtwoord" /> <hr /> <input type="
submit" onsubmit="checkEmail()" value="submit"/>

    </form>


function maakCookie(naam, waarde, dagen)
{
    if(dagen)
    {
        var datum = new Date();
        datum.setTime(datum.getTime() + (dagen * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var verloopdatum = "; expires="+datum.toGMTString();
    }
    else
    {
        var verloopdatum = "";
    }
    document.cookie = naam+"="+waarde + verloopdatum + ";path=/";
}

function checkEmail()
{
    alert("kijken of het werkt");
    if(/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za- z]{2,4}$/.test(document.userform.email.value))
    {
    return (true)
    }
    else
    {
    alert("het e-mailadres is onjuist")
    return (false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which `onsubmit`, the one in your `form` or the one in your `input`? You might want to post your `maakCookie` and `checkEmail` functions too.

Comment: What is `checkEmail` doing? It might be preventing the default action of the `submit` button.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  The JavaScript for the different functions would be a good start.

Comment: are your alerts firing? ie - does the onsubmit fire at all?

Comment: Do inputs even have a submit event? I thought that only applied to form elements.

Comment: No they aren't firing at all. My book says input and form have a submit event. And they are both not working

Comment: You might be better to have one function to both check email and make a cookie, as well as submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the `onsubmit` event on your input at all.

Just try the following :

```
<form onsubmit="checkEmail(); maakCookie('user',document.inlog.gebruiker.value,1); maakCookie('password',document.inlog.wachtwoord.value,1);" name="inlog" action="inloggen.html" method="post"> 

    email-adres: <input type="text" size="20" id="gebruiker" />
    wachtwoord: <input type="password" size="20" id="wachtwoord" />
    <hr />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onsubmit` in not an attribute for an `<input>`. If you want to check if your `onsubmit` is firing, you can create a simple function first like below:

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="tryalert();" action="" method="post">
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function tryalert()
{
     alert("working");
}
```

If something like that works, there is something wrong with your **`maakCookie`** function.